# How to use the returned value from a shell function in Makefile at runtime?

Tags: makefile

I use the result of a shell command on several places in my Makefile. The result is not known at the Makefile load time - it needs to be computed every time.

I tried the following:

```
cmd = echo "string"

target:
    ls $(call cmd)

Instead of ls string, I get ls echo string.
```

Comment: In your real code are you passing arguments to the `call` invocation?  Or is your real usage similar to the above, just `$(call cmd)`?

Comment: No parameters for now.

Comment: Note there is no difference between `$(call cmd)` and `$(cmd)`.  They do the same thing.  You might be interested to read http://make.mad-scientist.net/the-eval-function/ particularly the section on N-ary functions to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not really right for various technical reasons that may not matter in this trivial example but can bite hard in other situations.

It's always[*] an anti-pattern to use `shell` inside a recipe.  It can yield some very odd results in some situations.  The change you've made above does just that.

Instead, you want to use shell syntax for running a command and replacing its output: either via backticks or the newer `$(...)` syntax.  The latter has better nest-ability but is a bit more annoying to use in makefile recipes because it requires the dollar sign to be quoted.

You can either put this inside the variable, or outside, depending on your needs.  So one of these solutions is better:

```
cmd = `echo "string"`
target:
        ls $(call cmd)
```

or

```
cmd = $$(echo "string")
target:
        ls $(call cmd)
```

or

```
cmd = echo "string"
target:
        ls `$(call cmd)`
```

or

```
cmd = echo "string"
target:
        ls $$($(call cmd))
```

[*] There's always an exception to every rule ... :)

Comment: Thank you very much @MadScientist. You are right that `shell` can byte. I am not sure why though. I noted that `$$` is not executed when doing `make -n target`, while `shell` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of:
`cmd = echo "string"`
I used:
`cmd = $(shell echo "string")`.